# Forcing solutions to avoid Root[]

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-manipulation, differential-equations

I'm solving a system of ordinary non-homogeneous differential equations (4 equations). The solutions will include some algebraic equations solutions as known from text books due to the use of an eigen value problem. I'm fully aware that equations that are of degree 5 and more do not have an analytical general solution, however, degrees less than that have a general analytical solution.

Thus:

When I solve my differential equations with `DSolve[]`, I get the solution including many instances of

```
Root[a + b #1 + c #1^2 + d #1^3 + #1^4 &, 1]
```

where `a,b,c,d` are constant numbers. Now this is annoying for me as simplifying this expression algebraicly is not possible, leading to a huge solution.

I'm surprised why Mathematica is doing this. Why doesn't mathematica write the solutions formally? Notice that the general solution of the same equation is available when using:

```
Solve[a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + x^4 == 0, x]
```

I was able to get rid of all the `RootSum[]`s using the `Normal[]` function.

My question is: How can I get rid of all these `Root[]`?

EDIT:

Requested equations in comments:

```
Normal /@ DSolve[
{
S {Mex'[t], 
  Mey'[t]} == {ωe Mey[t] + λ ωe Mny[
     t], -ωe Mex[t] - λ ωe Mnx[
     t]} - {ΓRe Mex[t], ΓRe Mey[t]},
{Mnx'[t], 
 Mny'[t]} == {λ ωn Mey[t] + ωn Mny[
     t], -λ ωn Mex[t] - ωn Mnx[
     t]} - {ΓRnt Mnx[t], ΓRnt Mny[t]}
, Mex[0] == 0, Mey[0] == Me0, Mnx[0] == 0, Mny[0] == Mn0},
{Mex[t], Mey[t], Mnx[t], Mny[t]}, t]
```

Comment: Share the differential equations you try to solve.

Comment: @m0nhawk Is it OK to just copy the command from Mathematica? It's big and writing it formally is not simple.

Comment: Yes, just copy, I'll refine the formatting if needed.

Comment: @m0nhawk done. It's in the question.

Comment: And `Rnt` in the RHS in the second equation is $R\times n\times t$ and $t$ is a variable? Then the space should be before, otherwise *Mathematica* didn't respect it as a variable.

Comment: @m0nhawk No, no. `Rnt` isn't a product. `t` means transverse. Rnt is for Relaxation-nuclei-transverse.

Comment: The documentation says that `ToRadicals[expr]` attempts to express all `Root ` objects in `expr` in terms of radicals.

Comment: `DSolve` calls `Solve I believe so it might suffice to do `SetOptions[Solve,Quartics->True]`. Unless `DSolve temporarily overrides that setting..

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks. I'll try that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have toyed with code (notice that I use only first solution for [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html)).

```
eqs = {S Mex'[
      t] == ω e Mey[t] + λ ω e Mny[
       t] - Γ R e Mex[t], 
   S Mey'[t] == -ω e Mex[t] - λ ω e Mnx[
       t] - Γ R e Mey[t], 
   Mnx'[t] == λ ω n Mey[t] + ω n Mny[
       t] - Γ Rnt Mnx[t], 
   Mny'[t] == -λ ω n Mex[t] - ω n Mnx[
       t] - Γ Rnt Mny[t], Mex[0] == 0, Mey[0] == Me0, 
   Mnx[0] == 0, Mny[0] == Mn0};

f[x_] := Normal[DSolveValue[eqs, {Mex, Mey, Mnx, Mny}, t]][[1]][x];

Replace[f[x], {Root[x_, y_] :> ToRadicals[Root[x, y]]}, Infinity]
```

This code gets rid of [`Root`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects, but the output quiet long and [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) takes too long to finish (more than 30 minutes, and I stopped waiting).

If there is exist some simple solution, than maybe some other techniques can be applied to found it.

Comment: Thank you very much. That answers my question. But what do you mean with "notice that I use only the first solution for replace"? The `y` parameter is supposed to be the number of the solution, right?

Comment: Notice the `[[1]]` in the end of `f[x_]` definition. Just to show the proof-of-concept.

Comment: Oh, that. That's fine. Actually I didn't copy your whole code. I just copied the last line. It's all I need :-) Thanks again.